# Reminder doesn't navigate when user tap

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reminders

I use this code for creating a reminder in Windows Phone 8 app:

```
String name = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
reminder.Title = AppResources.ReminderTitle;
reminder.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;
reminder.NavigationUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

Very simple code. This reminder works fine except it doesn't navigate to my MainPage.xaml when i tap on it. It just closes the reminder. I also tried `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` in NavigationUri. This code is in AddReminderPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml is in the same folder. What am i doing wrong? Why it is not navigating to my app? Any idea?

Also i checked this documentation and did the exact same: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202965(v=vs.105).aspx#ADDREMINDERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202965%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#ADDREMINDERS)

Comment: You say that AddReminderPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml are in the same folder, but which folder is that?

Comment: I mean they are in the root folder. Top Level.

Comment: Then I think There is no reason for that to happen.
Just try this to see if it works:

`reminder.NavigationUri = new Uri(".\\MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);`

Comment: No, i doesn't work either. By the way if write an Uri that doesn't exist it gives me error. So  think Uri is correct. Weird

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `NavigationUri` is not supported on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/11b56732-c585-49f1-9757-9d6b68e1d5a0/reminder-navigationurl-doesnt-work-for-sl81-but-works-well-on-sl8?forum=silverlightwinphone